# Pointers to draw a shape like a squeezed bubble in iOS

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, curve

I'm trying to make a small bubble shape that toggles between a full circle and a squeezed shape. I came across [this article](http://ronnqvi.st/thinking-like-a-bzier-path/) that uses `UIBezierPath` broken down into straight lines and circles to make a rectangular shape with rounded corners. But before starting, I think it would be better if I could get some pointers on how to go forward. For ex, if I were to use `UIBezierPath`, then how would the path be broken down into individual curves in case of the squeezed bubble. The shape I'm thinking is an ellipse with concave bulges on two opposite sides, sort of like an hourglass. I couldn't figure out how to make this shape. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an image of the shape you want to draw. Or does "squeezed bubble" just mean an ellipse?

Comment: To animate the bubble squeeze, the bubble would go from a circle, then an ellipse and finally a curve with a bulge on two sides. I can manage the ellipse, it's the curve with concave bulges on two sides that I can't figure out.

Comment: Try some meatballs -- sorry, I meant [metaballs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs).

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2 code that creates UIBezierPath :

```
var borderWidth : CGFloat = 4 // Should be less or equal to the `radius` property
var radius : CGFloat = 10
var triangleHeight : CGFloat = 15

private func bubblePathForContentSize(contentSize: CGSize) -> UIBezierPath {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentSize.width, contentSize.height).offsetBy(dx: radius, dy: radius + triangleHeight)
    let path = UIBezierPath();
    let radius2 = radius - borderWidth / 2 // Radius adjasted for the border width

    path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(rect.maxX - triangleHeight * 2, rect.minY - radius2))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(rect.maxX - triangleHeight, rect.minY - radius2 - triangleHeight))
    path.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(rect.maxX, rect.minY), radius: radius2, startAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
    path.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(rect.maxX, rect.maxY), radius: radius2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), clockwise: true)
    path.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(rect.minX, rect.maxY), radius: radius2, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)
    path.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(rect.minX, rect.minY), radius: radius2, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), clockwise: true)
    path.closePath()
    return path
}
```

[image]

You can do whatever you want with this path. For example use it to setup CAShapeLayer and then add it to the view:

```
bubbleLayer.path = bubblePathForContentSize(contentView.bounds.size).CGPath
bubbleLayer.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor
bubbleLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.CGColor
bubbleLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
bubbleLayer.position = CGPoint.zero
myView.layer.addSublayer(bubbleLayer)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.This draws a shape that looks like a squeezed bubble.

```
/// Oval Drawing
UIBezierPath* ovalPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[ovalPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(151, 76)];
[ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(151.31, 38.76) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(172, 82) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(165.62, 27.52)];
[ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(99.69, 38.76) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(137, 50) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(113.94, 28.41)];
[ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(99.69, 76.24) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(85.44, 49.11) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(85.44, 65.89)];
[ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(151, 76) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(113.94, 86.59) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(130, 70)];
[ovalPath closePath];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[ovalPath fill];
```